# View model not writing to local database

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm

Submission of a view model does not write to local DB without throwing an error.

I have set the column value object.column name = value

```
reportService.UploadReport(dailyReport, environmentalReportUrl);
GuidGeneration guid_new = new GuidGeneration();
dailyReport.GUID= guid_new.ToString(); // no error before compiling
```

In Submission view model class, I need to track the submission to SharePoint with GUID, on submission to SharePoint Guid should be overwritten in local SQL lite DB, but the code cannot write to DB. It seems that can only write in ViewModel classes. This might be due to inheriting abstract classes but in general, what could cause the silent fail to write.

Comment: I apologize, there was a method    repository.Save(dailyReport); that I have not used in order to write to DB. This issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, there was a method repository.Save(dailyReport); that I have not used in order to write to DB. This issue is solved